# Can Not Run Hello World Program using Android Studio on Virtual Machine Hosted Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I am new to Android World. Currently I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on Oracle VM VirtualBox Managerr which is hosted on Window7. I was able to installed Android Studio successfully. However While running, I am getting the following error.

Could somebody suggest me a way to run/debug the app on my current environment.  Am i missing something obvious here. Please let me know in case any further information is required from my side.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVM is missing, means, you should read this tutorial:

http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2015/03/07/enabling-hardware-acceleration-for-android-sdk-emulator-on-linux/

> “INFO: KVM is disabled by your BIOS HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and
>   enable Virtualization Technology (VT), and then hard poweroff/poweron
>   your system KVM acceleration can NOT be used”

and of course, The next step is to install the KVM and a few other packages needed. To do so, type

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Add your user to some groups, replacing `<user>` by your own username:

```
sudo adduser <user> libvirtd
sudo adduser <user> kvm
```

Check if everything is ok.

Remember, HAXM is not compatible with linux.

**According to:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/600727/alternate-software-for-ubuntu

Comment: The `libvirt-bin` package was dropped in ^18.10

Answer (score 0):

Either your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours trying to solve this problem on my mac. It turns out that you need to enable/allow HAXM in System Perferances (Security/Privacy in the General Tab)